# front end editing obstructed

Tags: contacts, joomla

I just have activated front end editing at our test site (civicrm 5.10.2 and joomla 3.9.3)because some volunteers need a clean and simplified view to the sytem to edit contacts.

Performing a search in the fronted works fine, but selecting a user to be edited, the newsletter profile for the current user (log in user) shows between the user menu and the selected user data set. I digged around but could not find any setting to avoid this behavior, not in profiles nor other items so far.

[image: mailing list error]

This behavior is very disturbing and can not be accepted for a productive system. Do you have any hint about hiding this in editing view?

Thank you very much!

Bert Zimpel